# Fan count for a Facebook Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I needed to pull the fan count for particular fan pages on Facebook.  After digging through the API, I couldn't find a way to do this with the API "proper."  Instead I fell back to a FQL query, and it worked quite well.

```
select fan_count from page where page_id = <FAN_PAGE_ID>
```

What did I miss about the Facebook API.  Is this the only way to capture a fan count for a page?  In general, how often do you use FQL for your requests as opposed to the exposed API methods?

Comment: Sweet, my first Tumbleweed badge.

Comment: I've noticed the TumbleWeeds show up when asking facebook api questions.

Comment: Yeah, the tumbleweeds blow all the way over to the Facebook Developer forums.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

"fan_count" property. replace *cocacola* with your fan page's ID.

Please note that this property is being changed to "likes" in the [November 2010 Roundup migration](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap):

> Graph API: The fan_count attribute on
>   the Page object will be renamed to
>   likes.

You can opt in to the November Roundup in your application's advanced settings page.

Comment: Thanks.  It required Facebook to build a whole new API to support answering this question ;-)

Comment: At the time I'm posting this comment, I believe that this answer is out of date as there is no fan_count property on the linked page.

Comment: @mgilson cleary states that "fan_count" was changed to "likes" in November 2010, so it's not incorrect.