# FaceBook fan count on website

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'd like to include a within the footer of my website a "facebook fan count". I believe this will add an incentive to users considering clicking our facebook icon. "join XXXX fans on our facebook page" for example. I want the XXXX to be automatically populated with our facebook fan count. I want to do the same with twitter. Any insight you can provide would be helpful.

Note, I dont want to include the whole FB widget, just need the fan count for this purpose.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888515/fan-count-for-a-facebook-fan-page

Answer (score 1):

You can get the fan count of a page via their API using `Pages.getInfo` found [here](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Pages.getInfo).

Or using FQL:

```
select fan_count from page where page_id = [ID of Fan Page]
```

For Twitter you can get the followers_count from this call of `users/lookup` found [here](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-users-lookup).

Answer (score 0):

Do the following FQL query to the [facebook api](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fql.query):

```
select fan_count from page where page_id = <FAN_PAGE_ID>
```

For twitter you need to extract it from [a user query](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-users-lookup).

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

"fan_count" property. replace "cocacola" with your page ID.

Answer (score 0):

**FaceBook Graph API**

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api#selection

the new Graph api should work for you..

Replace the "**devilsworkshop.org**" with your page name and then
try opening page

https ://graph.facebook.com/devilsworkshop.org

It will return a object with **fan_count** as its member.